# uitable cannot be properly displayed after compilation

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, matlab-uitable

I have a uitable embedded in a GUI with cell structure, and it is editable.
Everything works fine within Matlab environment, but after compilation, the uitable only displays blank. It is still editable, but simply nothing shows up in the GUI.

P.S: I have included arrayviewfunc and other relevant functions in compilation. So missing functions should not be a potential cause in this case.
This bug has been fixed in 2008b, but I only have license of 2008a.
Nonetheless, it is quite important for my program so I'd like to consult here if any workarounds in 2008a exist.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you asked the Technical Support of Mathworks ? I remember a case in which they send a new function file to replace the bugged one on the asker computer. If the bug is known, it's probably possible.

Comment: In that case I have to go through all over the bureaucratic procedure since I am working with corp license.